# I setup a supply line but I dont see shared items?

Tags: fallout-4

I setup a supply line from Tenpines Bluff to Red Rocket Station and Sanctuary, but I dont see the shared items in the workstation? I have 50 Concrete in Sanctuary but can't see it in the Tenpines or Red Rocket station.
[image]

Can someone explain this to me?

Also how do I find the settler to delete the supply line?

Comment: It takes about 24 hours for it to start showing up. Have you traveled around or waited for 24 hours since setting it up?

Comment: Yeah I slept for 24 hours, and have run around probably another 12.

Comment: Have you actually tried *using* the components? You won't see them in the workshop when you try to transfer, but they should be available for use when crafting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know. I believe that you'll just use the materials from another settlement so long as they're linked. So if you're in Sanctuary Hills and you wanna build say, a bench which requires 5 wood and 1 steel, in Tenpines Bluff it'll just take the wood and steel out of Sanctuary's workshop inventory that is, if you don't already have the materials in Tenpines' inventory.

Comment: I do this without having supply lines.

Comment: @timelord you must have some in your inventory.  You can't use mats from another settlement until you set up a line

Comment: @z', im sure that is the intention, but I have already tested otherwise. It seems there is a bug where its concerned, though I'm not sure how it replicates, yet

Comment: @timelord64 it works as intended for me.  Whenever I clear a new settlement and have to put up a radio tower I usually don't have the mats on hand to build one so i have to set up a supply line to my main base first

Comment: Its funny, @z', thats exactly how I confirmed it to work without supply lines for me. Makes it confusing, as I wasn't sure what supply lines were for at all. Will post an update if I figure outwhat causes the bug

Answer (score 2):

Junk material can be used to build stuff in another settlement with a supply line, but you can not directly see it or remove it from the workstation. Just like settlers in another settlement can 'use' food from linked settlement but you can not see it directly (they will not be hungry even if you don't have enough food in your settlement as long as you have a supply line to another settlement which has enough surplus food).