# How does workshop sharing work?

Tags: fallout-4

From the descriptions I've seen online, once I have set up a supply line between two settlemens they should share resources. However, when I look at their respective inventories they seem separate.

How does resource sharing work, exactly? What happens when I set up a supply line?

Comment: probably a duplicate. candidates: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/244053/108003, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/242808/108003, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/243309/108003

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supply lines only deliver materials if you want to build something. The inventories are still shared. You can' take something from sanctuary if you look into the inventory of the castle, for example, even with an established supply line.

However, if you build something, you can access the resources of every village which is connected with supply lines. This does not require a direct route. You can establish a supply line from sanctuary to the castle, and from the castle to star-light dinner, and if you build something in sanctuary, you can use the materials and resources which are currently stored in in star-light dinner.

Comment: Specifically, raw materials and their un-scrapped sources are shared once you've set up supply lines.  Items you've constructed and/or stored in the workshop are NOT shared.

Comment: @drudge Not only. As far as i know, you can only access raw materials from the village they are stored in. While they can be used to built stuff somewhere else, you can only take them into your inventory from the village they are stored in.

Comment: @Y U NO WORK: Indeed, there is a difference between the items being "available as construction materials" and "can be moved to the player's inventory".